# Is it "extreme" or "large" diversity for endophytic microorganism subject?

Tags: terminology, plant-physiology

Do I need to substitute the word *extreme* to *large* in this text?

> Endophytic fungi are molds that are found in the healthy plant tissues. Endophytic fungi is mold that exists in the plant tissue systems, such as leaves, fruits, twigs,  or root of plants (Clay, 1988).  Endophytic microorganisms have **extreme diversity**, because they can inhabit the healthy plant tissue of all plant taxa in the mainland, especially in tropical timber plants (Arnold & Herre, 2003).

**Note: It is a microbiology/mycology field, that's why I posted on the biology site. It is not about a terminology, it is a condition related to endophytic microorganism and its diversity. Pity that they migrated it here.

Comment: I believe this question is better suited to ELL, as it requires no specialized knowledge of biology. That being said, I would suggest "endophytic microorganisms are extremely diverse".

Comment: @dd3 suited to ELL? Nope for this one! thanks anyway....

Comment: To this non-biologist (but former chemist), *extreme diversity* sounds fine; *large diversity* sounds strange in this context.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to your question is **No, you don't need to change the word *extreme* to *large*. You need to change the phrase in which the words *have extreme diversity* appear because this phrase is not idiomatic English. It's typical of stilted biomedical-speak, which I've been editing every day for 16.5 years**.

This is really a proofreading and editing question. There are many grammatical, syntax, and word-choice errors in the text. Here's an edited version that corrects them all and eliminates the verbosity and redundancy as well.

> Endophytic fungi are molds found in healthy plant tissue systems, such as leaves, fruit, twigs, and roots (Clay, 1988). Endophytic microorganisms are extremely diverse because they can inhabit the healthy tissue of all plant taxa, especially tropical timber plants, on the mainland (Arnold & Herre, 2003).